# How to break lines in URLs in stylesheet

Tags: css, url, data-uri

I have a stylesheet with really long lines (data urls).
Is there anyway I can break those lines into smaller lines?

Example of long line:

```
background-image: url(data: image/png;base64, really long string);
```

Comment: use code wrapping & folding features inside your editor

Comment: are you talking about the actual CSS file or just how it is presented in the IDE? Because in IDEs you could wrap long lines AFAIK. Not sure if breaking an actual base64 string would work.

Comment: And when it gets minified, it doesn't matter anyway.

Comment: Could you provide a proper Base64-encoded data URI for the sake of demonstration? It doesn't have to be a real-world image, a very simple bitmap would generate a reasonably long data URI for demonstration.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/r8b808bb/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You do this by enclosing the URI in quotes, and appending a `\` to the end of each line you want to break, followed by a newline, within the URI. [The parser will treat](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters) the string in the URI as though the `\` and the immediately following newline were not there.

When doing this with a URI that is not a Base64-encoded data URI, you need to make sure there is no indentation inside the string or the link will not work. This is because whitespace is significant in a URI. Whitespace is not significant in a Base64 string, so leaving indentation in a Base64-encoded data URI is fine, but that's a property of Base64 strings, not URIs. If this confuses you, for the sake of simplicity never indent.

Here's an example:

```css
#circle {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQ\
CAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAACxIAAAsSAdLdfvw\
AAAB6SURBVDhP3ZPLEcAgCERpwSYpLi3YgrWkBbLAIYHJZEi45fBUPq4jColIhIjBBmAF1Mc5/zSIBl\
jmekZzRhTwzbuZNTTXRGCZQOXkzHIBv3MOVmEVmMn5hqkCd4EyPxFoF7H5jJiwaHwkDJiaX1lxkY/Nd\
MVrUmxnoQPGWQ2Hnu//1wAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==');
}
```

```html
<div id=circle></div>
```

Comment: @Aziz: jsFiddle "helpfully" indented all the lines where you inserted line breaks for you. Remove the indentation and it will work.

Comment: @Aziz: Ahhhh, I missed something. You need to quote the URL.

Comment: If the url isn't quoted, will the parser fail?

Comment: @Poul Bak: Yes. The \ + newline thing only applies within strings.